# Having variables in rows and having the equation solve itself from them

Tags: google-sheets

Newbie on coding and don't know how to make it work: Have the equation and need to change 3 variables depending on the situation.

Tried to Google but I guess I don't know what I'm exactly looking for as English isn't my first language

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XI9AmNm.png]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HUw724okFB94GpeYmF3sacQBgQRnpnTSvgMMSk6RX4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=B4+(((B3/100)*280.059565*(B2^-0.412565956)-B3))
```

[image: 0]